# How to extract type parameters using reflection

Tags: go, generics, reflection, mapping, type-parameter

Context: I'm writing a generic auto-mapper that takes two types of structs, checks each field of said structs for a given tag, then copies the value from the source struct to the target struct assuming that they have matching tags and types. Whenever a struct field is another (nested) struct, I want the auto-mapper function to do a recursive call, auto-mapping all the way down the rabbit hole.

Problem: I'm only able to pass the concrete type of the root structs. Once I'm inside the generic function that's using reflection, trying to extract the nested struct types doesn't seem possible.
While I can pass the Value.Interface() as an argument, I still need to pass the type parameters as well.

Here is some simplified code to show the problem.

```
type Alpha struct {
    Nested Beta `automap:"nested"`
}

type Beta struct {
    Info string `automap:"info"`
}

type Foo struct {
    Nested Bar `automap:"nested"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Info string `automap:"info"`
}

func TestAutoMap(t *testing.T) {

    b := Beta{Info: "Hello from Beta!"}
    a := Alpha{Nested: b}

    f, err := AutoMap[Alpha, Foo](a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        t.Fail()
    }
    fmt.Println("f.nested.info:", f.Nested.Info)
}

func AutoMap[S, T any](source S) (target T, err error) {

    targetStruct := reflect.ValueOf(&target).Elem()
    sourceStruct := reflect.ValueOf(&source).Elem()

    // .Type and .Kind directly did not work.
    nestedSourceType := ??? // I want this to be type Beta.
    nestedTargetType := ??? // I want this to be type Bar.

    sourceInterface := sourceStruct.Interface()

    t, err := AutoMap[nestedSourceType, nestedTargetType](sourceInterface)
    if err != nil {
        return target, err
    }
    target = t

    return target, nil
}
```

Comment: You can't, it's not possible, the compiler is not gonna be able to generate functions for types it doesn't know about at compile time. However you can still implement what you want, just not the way you want, for example you could have `AutoMap` call `func autoMap(t, s reflect.Value) { ... [your reflection-based implementation] ... }`.

Comment: I have an 'any' type based approach that foregoes generics entirely as well, but that one relies on having the target struct set up beforehand instead of being instantiated inside the function and returned, which becomes a problem when nested structs fields are behind pointers, seeing as they'll then be set as nil pointers, disallowing the called function to set values. Essentially, I'd have to set up the entire recursive target struct, which kind of defeats the "auto" part of the desired mapper functionality. Am I chasing windmills here?

Comment: That's why I suggested that you keep `AutoMap` and have it call `autoMap` which would take `reflect.Value` as arguments. For example, just like you are doing in your question, `AutoMap` would initialize the `reflect.Value` instances from the pointers to the generic instances, then pass the reflect values to `autoMap` which will be able to use the `reflect.Value.Set` method, no matter how deeply nested the structs are. In other words, don't use `.Interface()` in the `autoMap`, use the `reflect.Value` as is.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/ulzLMHwMOEZ

Comment: Thank you, I will heed your advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having followed the advice of @[mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva), I want to share a simple solution to the problem I had.

Please feel free to correct or improve it, but keep in mind that I am deliberately not including all sorts of checks and assertions below.

([Go Playground Example](https://go.dev/play/p/FLDLmx6A6Qi))

```
type Alpha struct {
    NestedOnce Beta
}

type Beta struct {
    NestedTwice Gamma
}

type Gamma struct {
    Info string
}

type Foo struct {
    NestedOnce Bar
}

type Bar struct {
    NestedTwice Baz
}

type Baz struct {
    Info string
}

func TestAutoMap(t *testing.T) {

    g := Gamma{"Hello from Gamma!"}
    b := Beta{g}
    a := Alpha{b}

    f, err := AutoMap[Foo](a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        t.Fail()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Foo.NestedOnce.NestedTwice.Info:", f.NestedOnce.NestedTwice.Info)
    }
}

func AutoMap[T any](source any) (target T, err error) {

    // Peel off 'any' from the function parameter type.
    sourceStruct := reflect.ValueOf(&source).Elem().Elem()

    targetStruct := reflect.ValueOf(&target).Elem()

    err = autoMap(sourceStruct, targetStruct)

    return target, err
}

func autoMap(s, t reflect.Value) error {

    sourceField := s.Field(0)
    targetField := t.Field(0)

    if sourceField.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        err := autoMap(sourceField, targetField)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }

    targetField.Set(sourceField)

    return nil
}
```